# Как установить время жизни refresh token?

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, jwt

Вот таким способом генерирую рефреш токен. Не знаю как установить ему время жизни. Сохраняю его в таблицу AspNetUserToken. Если моё понимание правильно, то токены должни работать так: я отправляю на сервер логин и пароль, получаю ацес и рефреш токен. Допустим я установил у ацес токена время жизни 5 минут, а в рефреш 10 мин. и когда время жизни ацес токена заканчивается, то рефреш токен генерирует его еще раз, и я могу дальше пользоваться сайтом без перезахода на сайт. А если уже закончилось время жизни у рефреш токена, то оно просит перезайти на сайт. Я правильно понимаю? И вот в таком случае когда я так генерирую и записываю токен в таблицу, то я не знаю какой у него срок жизни, вот и хочу ему установить свой срок. Подскажите, пожалуйста, или направьте на правильный путь.

```
public async Task<string> GenerateNewRefreshTokenAsync(string email)
{
    if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(email))
    {
        throw new ServerException(Constants.Errors.EMAIL_IS_EMPTY);
    }

    var user = await _userManager.FindByEmailAsync(email);

    if (user is null)
    {
        throw new ServerException(Constants.Errors.USER_NOT_FOUND);
    }

    await _userManager.RemoveAuthenticationTokenAsync(user, Constants.Token.MY_APP, Constants.Token.REFRESH_TOKEN);
    var newRefreshToken = await _userManager.GenerateUserTokenAsync(user, Constants.Token.MY_APP, Constants.Token.REFRESH_TOKEN);
    await _userManager.SetAuthenticationTokenAsync(user, Constants.Token.MY_APP, Constants.Token.REFRESH_TOKEN, newRefreshToken);

    return newRefreshToken;
}
```

Comment: Рефреш токен по  идее одноразовый. Когда ацесс токен кончится, рефреш токен используется для получения новой пары ацесс и рефреш токенов.

Comment: Поддерживаю tym32167. Но если есть большая необходимость, то в таблицу AspNetUserToken никак. Только если допустим у вас таблица пользователей наследована от IdentityUser, вы можете в сущность пользователя добавить условное RefreshTokenDate, в которое писать последнюю дату создания RefreshToken и уже по ней сверять. Это как пример.

Comment: @funforlifefix Спасибо буду пробывать